# SwiftUI - Working with rows & columns in a matrix

Tags: ios, arrays, swiftui, foreach

I've created a Core Data entity with the following attributes:
[image]

And I've managed to manually enter 5 instances of "Round" so that I have 5 "rows" of data and have confirmed that Core Data is working.

Question is how to now add up the "columns" in the matrix (for the Int64 values), to then divide by number of "rows", i.e., to calculate the average for each column?

I'm a newbie, so any help appreciated.

Also, if I create a func to perform those calculations, can I merely call it immediately after the Core Data FetchRequest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create functions in your code and call them on the fetched core data. Also you would not need the `total` attribute in core data as you can calculate it on the fly.

I am assuming your FetchRequest generates an Array of `Round` called `coredata`

```
func total(round: Round) -> Int64 {
    return round.pos1 + round.pos2 + round.pos3 + round.pos4 + round.pos5
}

func columnSum(pos: Int) -> Int64 {
    switch pos {
    case 1: return coredata.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.pos1 })
    case 2: return coredata.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.pos2 })
    case 3: return coredata.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.pos3 })
    case 4: return coredata.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.pos4 })
    case 5: return coredata.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.pos5 })
    default: return 0
    }
}

func columnAverage(pos: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(columnSum(pos: pos)) / Double(coredata.count)
}
```

Then you can do something like this in your view:

```
Text("Average row 1: \(columnAverage(pos: 1))")
```

Comment: Excellent.  Appreciated, ChrisR.  Two more questions... 1) If I wanted to iterate through the rows of the array to calculate the total for pos1 thru pos5 of each row, how would I do that?  2) What do the "switch" & "case X:" terms do?  I am unfamiliar with either term?  Thanks again.

Comment: 1) that is exactly what `columnSum` does: `coredata.reduce` iterates over all elements of the coredata array and sums them up. 2) `switch case` does something like `if pos==1 do ..., if pos==2 do... if pos==3 do ...` etc.

Comment: Really appreciate the help & explanation, Chris.  Thanks.

Comment: welcome :) ...and to answer 1) fully: `return coredata.reduce(0, { $0 + total(round: $1) })`

Comment: One other thought as to the `total`, if you wanted it available in any view that used `Round` you could make it a computed var in an extension of `Round`. Then you would be back to using it as `round.total` in any view. This would not work for the column totals, though.

Comment: @ChrisR - Hi Chris, sorry to bother you, but I've now started to implement the code and have another question (and apologies, I'm a total newbie).  Where do the "returns" go?  I assume it's the "case 1... 5", but I don't know how to pass  the calculations to my view?